# SwiftUI - TextField disabled - How to select and copy text?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

Like the Title says, the user need to copy a part of the text from a disabled textField.
This doesn't work for none of the OS'n. Not even macOS.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
 @State private var txt = "Hello StackOverFlowers"
 @State private var isDisabled : Bool = false

 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            TextField(txt, text: $txt)
                .foregroundColor(isDisabled ? Color.gray : .blue)
                .font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 24))
                .lineSpacing(5)
                .disabled(isDisabled)
            
            
            Text(txt).frame(width: 300,  alignment: .leading)
            
            Toggle(isOn: $isDisabled){ Text("TextField diasable toggle") }
        }
    }
}
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
 }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this working?
Or is there a way to have a TextField non editable but still selectable?

Comment: SwiftUI TextField does not have such feature for now, use representable wrapper for UI/NSTextField.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of that. I will look into that.